# How to run MEGA Sync on power on

Tags: startup, mega

I can't figure out how to run the MEGA Sync client as the same way the smb runs in my PC. I mean, in a way that the MEGA Sync synchronizes the files even if no user is logged in the PC.

How should I proceed?

Comment: You could use megatools, but megatools can not be installed parallel to megasync.

Answer (score 0):

Start a `megasync` client gui. Right click on the indicator and choose "Settings". Then make sure that "Start on startup" option is checked in Account section. Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work if no user is logged in.